# Why, after downloading Internet Explorer, do I get Google Chrome instead?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I bought a new laptop with Windows 7 and Chrome pre-installed -- no IE.  Not in the Programs menu, the Desktop, etc., but I need it!  So I downloaded it online, but it still didn't appear.  I even tried uninstalling Chrome then installing IE, but Chrome re-appeared.  So, where could IE be?

Comment: Internet Explorer 9 is much more modern in appearance than its predecessors and configured correctly can look similar to Chrome. forgive me for asking but, are you sure it is Chrome on your new laptop and not IE9?

Comment: This page will reveal which web browser you're running:  http://www.searchbin.ca/whatismyip.pl

Comment: It might just be that Chrome is set as the default browser.  Can you open Internet Explorer from the Start Menu?  Click the pretty Start button at the bottom left, type Internet Explorer and press Enter.  Does it open?

Answer (score 1):

From your Start Menu, select Control Panel -> Programs and Features. On the left-hand side of the screen, you'll see a link for 'Turn Windows features on or off'. It will have a small shield next to it.

Click the link, and in the resulting dialog, make sure that Internet Explorer is check marked. If it's not, it won't be available to you.